# Project Euler #3 with python - MOST EFFICIENT METHOD

Tags: python, performance

I have solved this but I was wondering what the most efficient method of solving this problem was (under 10s).

Problem can be found at [Projecteuler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=3).

Comment: "Under 10s" in terms of what?

Comment: and you should at least post a link to the problem or the text

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is probably the fastest and most compact way of doing it, taking just **141 milliseconds** and giving the answer `6857`.

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

```
n = 600851475143
i = 2
while i * i < n:
    while n % i == 0:
        n = n / i
    i = i + 1

print n
```

<sup>Code taken from [here](http://www.s-anand.net/euler.html)</sup>

Comment: I know this is old but, why does this return 25 for input 100?  Largest prime factor is 5.

Comment: @diatrevolo Because the given algorithm is buggy for squares. Try 25 or 16 and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Interesting.  Does the same with 200?  Anyway, just curious, thanks @Ringil!

Comment: This should use the `//` operator for division, for upward compatibility with Python 3.

Comment: cribbed and incorrect...

Comment: so, from I can understand.  divide `n` by progressively bigger `i`.  as soon it's evenly divisible, then, it stands to reason, the other side is about as big as it gets.  manipulate it a bit and... out's your result.  don't check that it's a prime, but it happens to be one in the case of euler3's `n`. and it happens to be the right answer too.  fails on pretty much any other `n`?  no problemo.

Comment: This algorithm only works if index of the max prime factor is $1$. If $n = k.p^m$, where $p$ is the max prime factor, and $gcd(k,p)=1$, then the output of the program is $p^m$ if $m=1,2$, otherwise output is $1$

Comment: The function in the answer has bug, it dont works for every number.

Comment: The code basically does a prime factorization of the given number. This is smart, but if the given number is already a prime, it's going to perform trial division with O(n) complexity. The sieve of Erastothenes would be a better solution for generic cases. Here, the code works because PE number is not a prime