# Prime factors in python

Tags: python, prime-factoring

I am looking for prime factors of 2500 with the code below, but my code only prints 2 currently and I am unsure why this is the case.

```
no = 2500
count = 0
# Finding factors of 2500
for i in range(1,no):
    if no%i == 0:
    # Now that the factors have been found, the prime factors will be determined  
        for x in range(1,no):
            if i%x==0: 
                count = count + 1
            """Checking to see if the factor of 2500, itself only has two factor implying it is prime"""  
                if count == 2:
                    print i
```

Thanks

Comment: The algorithm doesn't make too much sense to me, care to explain it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Finding Prime Factors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347174/python-finding-prime-factors)

Comment: Bad indentation, you only print something if count==2...

Comment: Shouldn't the second `for` loop be indented further?

Comment: @filmor I hope it is clearer

Comment: @Chris I've made the required indentations now. Thanks.

Comment: the only time i%x ==0 is at the start of your second for loop when i and x are both = 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using  [sieve of eratosthenes](https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes&ei=W1djU-_cKI_y7Ab0k4CIDg&usg=AFQjCNH4_KJuHBIzfPUZ1U2k9cvjys0laA&sig2=oRyRjMOc4oMerDESyT_XRw&bvm=bv.65788261,d.ZGU) to first generate list of primes:

```
 from math import sqrt
def sieve_of_eratosthenes(n):
    primes = range(3, n + 1, 2) # primes above 2 must be odd so start at three and increase by 2
    for base in xrange(len(primes)):
        if primes[base] is None:
           continue
        if primes[base] >= sqrt(n): # stop at sqrt of n
            break
        for i in xrange(base + (base + 1) * primes[base], len(primes), primes[base]):
            primes[i] = None
    primes.insert(0,2)
    sieve=filter(None, primes)
    return  sieve

def prime_factors(sieve,n):
    p_f = []
    for prime in sieve:
        while n % prime == 0:
            p_f.append(prime)
            n /= prime
    if n > 1:
        p_f.append(n)
    return p_f
sieve = sieve_of_eratosthenes(2500)
print prime_factors(sieve,2500)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I don't really understand your algorithm but if you're interested in finding the factors of a number, you could the following (based on your algorithm) :

```
no = 2500
factors = [i for i in range(1,no) if no % i == 0]
count = len(factors)
```

In this example, factors will hold the following list :

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100, 125, 250, 500, 625, 1250]
```

In particular for a prime number, count will be 1.

Edit: Ok, so I did misunderstand the question. The list contains merely the dividers and not the prime factors... Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

Your count variable will be only once == 2.

```
n = 2500
prime_factors = []

for p in range(2,n):
    if p*p > n: break
    while n % p == 0:
        prime_factors.append(p)
        n /= p
if n > 1: prime_factors.append(n)

print prime_factors
```

You get the prime factors of 2500 as a list back.
If you use only the prime numbers from 2 to 2500 instead of range(2,n) it'll be faster.
[Wikipedia - Trial division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division.)