# check prime factors of a number

Tags: python-2.7

Here I meet a problem to check the factors of a prime number

```
# using python2.7.10
from math import sqrt
def isprime(x):
    if x == 1:
        return False
    k = int(sqrt(x))
    for j in range(2,k+1):
        if x%j == 0:
            return False
        return True
num = input("please input a number:")
for i in range(2, num):
    if i!= num and num % i == 0:
        print i,
```

If I input a number 45, it prints out 3,5,9,15. However, 3 is a factor of 9 and 15, 5 is a factor of 15. I hope the results are 3, 5.
How can I change my code in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: Find primes from `2` to `sqrt(x)` using the Sieve of Eratosthenes, then iterate over these *primes* only; as soon as you find a factor, you can *divide* by it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move the *return True* out of the loop, so you check all numbers for 2 - k :

```
from math import sqrt

def isprime(x):
    if x == 1:
        return False
    k = int(sqrt(x))
    for j in range(2,k+1):
        if x % j == 0:
            return False
    return True # if you get here, you have checked all 2-k

num = int(raw_input("please input a number:"))
for i in range(2, num):
     if isprime(i) and num % i == 0:
        print(i,)
```

You `return True`  anytime that `if x % j == 0` has a remainder so you don't check x against all the numbers. Also, *don't use input* to take user-input, use *raw_input* casting to int i.e `num = int(raw_input())`.

A more efficient way to do what to you want is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423037/prime-factors-in-python/23423821#23423821)

Comment: sorry for lack of precision in my question. I hope to find prime factors of a number. 3 and 5 are prime factors of 45 but 9 and 15 are not. Now my code can just find all factors but not prime one.

Comment: I find a way to achieve my goal change a loop in last 2 line.  
# if isprime(i) and num% i ==0:

Comment: @CharlieCai, I added a link to another answer of mine that will be more efficient than your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, It will help you to get your ans:

```
def isprime(x):
    if x >= 2:       
        for k in range(2,x):
            if x%k==0:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False 


num = input("please input a number:")
factor=[]
prime_factor=[]
for i in range(2, num):
    if num % i == 0:
        factor.append(i)

for k in factor:    
    if isprime(k):        
        prime_factor.append(k)

print 'Factors',factor
print 'Prime Factors',prime_factor
```

Output--

```
please input a number:45
Factors [3, 5, 9, 15]
Prime Factors [3, 5]
```

Comment: Great,I also make a small change in my code, then it can work.

Comment: @CharlieCai Great, I think my ans is also correct still people gives me down vote, anyway well done.

Answer (score 0):

```
def isPrime(n):
isDivisible = False
i=2
while i<n:
    if n%i == 0:
        isDivisible = True
    i += 1
if isDivisible == False:
    return True
    #print(n," is a prime number!")
else: 
    return False
    #print(n,: is not a prime number!")


import pdb    
def primeFactors(n):
lst = []

while n>1:
    #pdb.set_trace()
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        if isPrime(i) and (n%i==0):
            #pdb.set_trace()
            lst.append(i)
            n = n//i
return lst


  
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print("The Prime Factors of the entered number are: ",primeFactors(x))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code to check prime or not . You can modify as you wish

```
prime_numbers = 0

def is_prime_number(x):
    if x >= 2:
        for y in range(2,x):
            if not ( x % y ):
                return False
    else:
    return False
    return True


for i in range(int(raw_input("How many numbers you wish to check: "))):
    if is_prime_number(i):
        prime_numbers += 1
        print i

print "We found " + str(prime_numbers) + " prime numbers."
```

Comment: I can find prime in my code, but I hope to find the minimum factor of that prime and print them out.

Comment: Smallest or Least ?

Comment: I have got my results via changing a condition. Thanks a lot : )

Answer (score -1):

Just to build slightly on vikram singh chandel's answer, this is a shorter solution that avoids the double for loop in the end. We only need to append factors that are primes:

**EDIT:** Minor change to cover for entering a prime number directly.

```
def isprime(x):

    if x < 2:
        return False

    for k in range(2, x):
        if x % k == 0:
            return False

    return True


num = input("please input a number:")

factors = []
for i in range(1, num + 1):
    if num % i == 0 and isprime(i):
        factors.append(i)

print 'Factors:', factors
```