# I cant figure out whats wrong with this code (python)

Tags: python

```
def primefactors():
    prime_list = []
    n = 600851475143
    for i in range(0, n):
        if i % n == 0:
            prime_list.append(i)
    return prime_list


print (primefactors())
```

I want to print out the numbers i have stored in prime_list

I dont get any errors but it dosnt print out anything..

Comment: because the if condition is never gonna to be evaluated as True.

Comment: You are finding numbers that are divisible by `600851475143`, not prime factors. There are no such numbers between `0` and `600851475142`, which is what your loop over. Ergo, your list is empty.

Comment: `600851475143` this number is very suspicious ... Any online course question?

Comment: @BhargavRao: It's Project Euler. See [Python Finding Prime Factors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15347174)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to swap i and n here:

```
i % n
```

Though, this code won't give you the prime factors, just the numbers that your n is divisible by.

Comment: You'll also need to change your range to start from 1 rather than 0