# Compute prime factors in python

Tags: python

I currently have a list containing numbers:

```
lst = [3,4,6]
```

and I'm trying to compute the prime factors of the numbers in the list where i obtain the output of

```
3^1
2^2
2^1 x 3^1
```

Here's what i tried:

```
def prime_factors(lst):
   for j in range(len(lst)):
       i = 2
       factors = []
       while i*i <= j:
           if j%i:
               i+=1
           else:
               j//= i
               factors.append(i)
       if j > 1:
           factors.append(j)
  return factors
```

but I'm getting [2] as the output. Would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: your `while i*i <= j:` condition is the problem. It exits when `i*i`  is `<=` the value of of element on the list and your initial condition is `i=2` so for `4` , `i*i` matches the exit condition and hence the code does not go into the loop.  
Also you are not going to get prime factors with this code. as you do incremental increase of `i` and not go through a list of primes.

Comment: Also, I think you want to use `for j in lst:` rather than `for j in range(len(lst)):` as at the moment, the values of lst aren't being accessed. You're iterating through from 0,1,2,... up to the length of the list.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com contains a ton of examples of _working_ code. Look at them.

Comment: have a look at [primefac module](https://pypi.org/project/primefac/) and at this so [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347174/python-finding-prime-factors).

Answer (score 0):

Well i did it from scratch , It uses a modification of the prime number sieve algorithm .

```
from math import sqrt
from collections import Counter
def prime_factors(lst):
    maximumnumber=max(lst)
    primesieve=[0]*(maximumnumber+1)
    primesieve[0]=1
    primesieve[1]=1
    #DOING PRIME NUMBER SIEVE
    for i in range(2,int(sqrt(maximumnumber))+1):
        if(primesieve[i]==0):
            for j in range(2*i,len(primesieve),i):
                primesieve[j]=i

    for j in range(len(lst)):
        num=lst[j]
        factors=[]
        #take each number(num) and divided it by a prime number (primesieve[num])
        #do it until you find no more prime factors for number
        while(primesieve[num]>0):

            factors.append(primesieve[num])
            num=num//primesieve[num]
        factors.append(num)
        yield Counter(factors)

for i in prime_factors([3,4,6]):
    print(i)
```

Output

```
Counter({3: 1})
Counter({2: 2})
Counter({2: 1, 3: 1})
```

Ill explain what i have done

1. Found prime numbers between the 0 and maximum element in the list using the prime number sieve algorithm , [Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/) to a the algorithm , I just modified one part that algorithm that is instead of using a the primenumber array as boolean i used ,Integer to show which number it was divided with
2. Iterate through the numbers and find all the prime factors