# Is there a function in Python 3 that will get the prime factors of any number?

Tags: math, prime-factoring

I'm making a Calculator and I want to know if there is a function in python that allows me to find the prime factors of any number.

Comment: [Write your own function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22808285/8881141) What is the upper limit of your numbers?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/primefac/

Comment: No, there is no such function. You can check for yourself [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html). There are other libraries out there that can do it, for example [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.factor_.factorint)