# Python: Prime Factorisation large integer division consistently returning incorrect result

Tags: python, math, floating-point, division, prime-factoring

I have some code like so:

```
def prime_factorisation(num):
    prime_factorisation_list = []
    prime = 2
    while prime**2 <= num:
        if not num % prime:
            prime_indexes = [item[0] for item in prime_factorisation_list]
            if prime in prime_indexes:
                position_in_list = prime_indexes.index(prime)
                prime_factorisation_list[position_in_list][1] += 1  # Increments count for prime factor
            else:
                prime_factorisation_list.append([prime, 1])  # Creates count for prime factor in the form [prime, count]
            num /= prime
        else:
            prime += 1
    if num > 1:
        prime_factorisation_list.append([int(num), 1])
    return prime_factorisation_list


number = 2938475648329038472
print(prime_factorisation(number))
```

It is a prime factorisation algorithm that returns a list of lists in the form:
[[prime factor 1, no. of times it occurs], [prime factor 2, no. of times it occurs], ...]

However the line: `num /= prime` seems to give me the wrong result.
I think it is an issue with floating point division, because when I substitute it for `num //= prime` it, it returns the correct result.

I know the maximum value of a floating point is 309 digits, but this is much less than that. I am also essentially doing integer division (dividing a number by one of its factors), so the decimal places should be point zero.

Could anyone explain to me why this occurs?

Comment: A floating point number does not store 309 digits.  It can store values up to 10**309, but it's only storing the first 17 significant digits.  THAT'S the problem.

Comment: You can also check this for yourself: `print(2938475648329038472 / 2)` -> `1.4692378241645192e+18` and `print(2938475648329038472 // 2)` -> `1469237824164519236`. The last 2 values are rounded off in your first case.

Comment: Oh, I always assumed the 1.xxx e+yyy meant the whole number was being saved but only some was being displayed (similar to a calculator).

Comment: A [module that finds prime factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347174/python-finding-prime-factors)

Answer (score 1):

It gives you the correct result because // is the integer division, and your intention is to find the prime factors.

Real division is unacurate by itself. Take a look to this [document ("what every programmer should know about floating point arithmetic")](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). about the matter.