# How to check if X is a divisor of 60 to power of any integer?

Tags: python, math

I have a big and random number **n** and I need to check if this number is a divior of 60 to the power of **ANY** integer

*For example:*

Input:

> 9

Output:

> True

because it is a divisor of 60^2

- I have looked into factorization of numbers and divisiors to find a
  schematic but I was unsucessful

Comment: 225 is a divisor of 3600 and it's not divisible by 2

Comment: This may be a trivial comment but I want to say that this is a lovely question and I look forward to seeing answers.

Comment: 2 to what power is divisible by 60?  I could ask the same about 3 or 5. This problem is not so trivial.

Comment: The set of prime factors of the number should be a subset of {2, 3, 5}.

Comment: @Arne {2} is a subset of {2,3,5} however 2^n%60 is not 0 for all n.

Comment: @kpie isn't the question what powers of 60 are divisible by, not the other way round?

Comment: OK.  In **prime numbers** it should be divisible only by 2, 3, or 5

Comment: @Arne my bad I was looking at the problem the wrong way around.

Comment: The question is if there is any power of 60 that has divisor N, and 0<N<10^18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at it this way:

```
60 = 2^2 * 3 * 5
60^2 = 2^4 * 3^2 * 5^2
60^3 = 2^6 * 3^3 * 5^3
...
```

So a positive integer `n` is a divisor of some power of 60 if and only if it can be written as

```
n = 2^k * 3^l * 5^m,
```

with `k`, `l`, and `m` being some integers >= 0.

In other words, the set of prime factors of `n` must be a subset of {2, 3, 5}.

Comment: Predicting further question: [Python Finding Prime Factors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15347174/10824407).

Comment: It takes about four lines of python code to do this.